# Gulp is changing the system register name automatically when importing namespace

Tags: angular, typescript, gulp, tsconfig

I have the following hierarchy:

[image]

**constants.ts**

```
export namespace Constants {
    export const root = "dist/";
}
```

**app.components.ts**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: "my-app",
    templateUrl: "dist/views/app.component.html",
})
export class AppComponent {
    public name = "Test !";
    public lastName = "App !";
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule }      from "@angular/core";
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";

import { AppComponent }  from "./components/app.component";

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**main.ts**

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic";

import { AppModule } from "./app.module";

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

**gulpfile.js**

```
var ts = require("gulp-typescript");
var tsProject = ts.createProject("tsconfig.json");
gulp.task('build:ts', () => {
    log('Compiling TypeScript --> JavaScript');
    return tsProject.src()
        .pipe(tsProject())
        .js.pipe(gulp.dest(config.jsDist));
});
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "include": [
    "./App/TypeScript/**/main.ts"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "declaration": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "system",
    "out": "main.min.js"
  },
  "sortOutput": true,
   "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/index",
    "typings/index.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

When I run the *build:ts*, on the output script that is generated, I get something like this:

```
System.register("main", ["@angular/platform-browser-dynamic", "app.module"],
function(exports_3, context_3) {..});
```

But I get this only when there is no importing to any modules/namespaces.

If I change the *app.components.ts* to

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

//This is the change:
import { Constants } from "../../common/constants/constants";

@Component({
    selector: "my-app",
    templateUrl: "dist/views/app.component.html",
})
export class AppComponent {
    public name = "Test !";
    public lastName = "App !";
}
```

I will get this output:

```
System.register("ui/main", ["@angular/platform-browser-dynamic", 
"ui/app.module"], function(exports_4, context_4) { ... });
```

So my questions are:

1. How the name is generated ?
2. Why it is changing when there are imports ?